# How to stop any sql by ACCOUNTADMIN

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Even a user with the ACCOUNTADMIN role cannot view the results for a query run by another user.
How can ACCOUNTADMIN can stop any sql running  by any user.
just want to check if this understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions in Snowflake that may help you:

1. SYSTEM$CANCEL_QUERY to cancel a query by it's ID: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_cancel_query.html
2. SYSTEM$CANCEL_ALL_QUERIES to cancel all queries in a session: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_cancel_all_queries.html

On top of that you can abort all queries of

1. a warehouse by executing `ALTER WAREHOUSE myWarehouse ABORT ALL QUERIES;`
2. an user by executing `ALTER USER myUser ABORT ALL QUERIES;`